# FileNotFoundException in Azure Synapse when trying to delete a Parquet file and replace it with a dataframe created from the original file

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse

I am trying to delete an existing Parquet file and replace it with data in a dataframe that read the data in the original Parquet file before deleting it.  This is in Azure Synapse using PySpark.

So I created the Parquet file from a dataframe and put it in the path:

```
full_file_path
```

I am trying to update this Parquet file.  From what I am reading, you can't edit a Parquet file so as a workaround, I am reading the file into a new dataframe:

```
df = spark.read.parquet(full_file_path)
```

I then create a new dataframe with the update:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_table")
df_variance = spark.sql("""SELECT * FROM temp_table WHERE ....""")
```

and the df_variance dataframe is created.

I then delete the original file with:

```
mssparkutils.fs.rm(full_file_path, True)
```

and the original file is deleted.  But when I do any operation with the df_variance dataframe, like df_variance.count(), I get a FileNotFoundException error.  What I am really trying to do is:

```
df_variance.write.parquet(full_file_path)
```

and that is also a FileNotFoundException error.  But I am finding that any operation I try to do with the df_variance dataframe is producing this error.  So I am thinking it might have to do with the fact that the original full_file_path has been deleted and that the df_variance dataframe maintains some sort of reference to the (now deleted) file path, or something like that.  Please help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark dataframes aren't collections of rows.  Spark dataframes use "deferred execution".  Only when you call

```
df_variance.write
```

is a spark job run that reads from the source, performs your transformations, and writes to the destination.

A Spark dataframe is really just a query that you can compose with other expressions before finally running it.

You might want to move on from parquet to delta. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-what-is-delta-lake